# InfoPath Getuserprofilebyname remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, user-profile

We are facing an issue to connect the User Profile (Method `GetUserProfilebyName`) through SOAP Service. We are getting below error:

> The specified location does not exist or could not be opened. Choose a data connection library on a server running Microsoft Office SharePoint Server and specify a valid filename

Reference Link: 
[How to resolve error creating universal data connection file (.udcx)?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118451/how-to-resolve-error-creating-universal-data-connection-file-udcx)